# Linkedin API: adAnalyticsV2 shows that impressions decrease over time

Tags: linkedin-api

Our team collecting member analytics lifetime-like data (in other words, a snapshot of data for current date) broken down by campaigns:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?
q=analytics&
pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&
dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.month=1&dateRange.start.year=2000&
dateRange.end.day=31&dateRange.end.month=10&dateRange.end.year=2020&
timeGranularity=ALL&
accounts[0]={{account}}&oauth2_access_token={{access_token}}&
fields=dateRange,pivot,pivotValue,impressions,clicks,externalWebsiteConversions&
campaigns[0]={{campaign}}&
projection=(*,elements*(dateRange(*),pivot,pivotValue~(localizedName),impressions,clicks,externalWebsiteConversions))
```

And I noticed a strange thing: for some retrieved organizations **we got fewer impressions than the day before**. Moreover, when I checked impressions for this date/campaign then their number has become even smaller. E.g., we keep in DB such impressions number for some campaign and member's organization:

2020-10-30  564

2020-10-31  557

And I've checked today (2020-11-04) data for 2020-10-31 (please see request above) and got 555 impressions!

How could this be possible? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Very strange, try asking to the direct support... Could be related to the pivot `MEMBER_COMPANY` ?  Could be the member of a company may vary in the time?

Comment: @Eegene Teretyev How did you not get this errror with they query above b'{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Unpermitted fields present in PARAMETER: Data Processing Exception while processing fields [/dateRange.start.year, /dateRange.end.month, /campaigns[0], /dateRange.start.day, /dateRange.start.month, /dateRange.end.year, /dateRange.end.day]","status":403}'
?